# Field History object - value of column "Field" when tracked field is lookup (standard v custom)

Tags: describefieldresult, field-history

I'm trying to selectively delete an SObject's field histories based on the members of an sobject's fieldset (think PII deletion - feature available V42).

**Example**: OOTB Order with field set containing:

- `BilltoContactId`
- `Custom_Lookup__c`
- `My_Decimal_Field__c`

Well, it turns out that this query (generated from the fieldset's members' fieldPath):

```
Select Id, Field From OrderHistory 
  Where OrderId = '...' AND 
        Field IN 
          ('BilltoContactId','Custom_Lookup__c','My_Decimal_Field__c')
```

will not return any records where `BillToContactId` changed (*and yes, field history tracking is enabled on that field*)

**It appears that ...**

- For an OOTB SObject lookup to an OOTB SObject, the lookup field's fieldpath in the fieldSet is `xxxId` but the value of the `Field` column in the `xxxHistory` object is simply `xxx`. Example: `BilltoContactId` in fieldset but `BilltoContact` in `OrderHistory.Field`.
- For custom SObjects, a lookup field's fieldpath in the fieldset is `yyy__c` and the value of the `Field` column in the `xxxHistory` object is also `yyy__c`. Example: `Custom_Lookup__c` in both fieldset and `OrderHistory.Field`.

*So ... what to do?*

**Option 1**

- Code a bit of heuristics using the field's describe and, if `!isCustom()` and `!getReferenceTo().isEmpty()`, then strip `ID` off the field API name to get a `xxxHistory`-queryable `Field` value.

**Option 2**

> Is there something more robust?

Comment: I'm not sure it's more robust (cf. this [unanswered question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117010/do-standard-lookups-always-follow-fieldname-relationshipname-id)) but using `getRelationshipName()` on the field describe seems to always return that core element of the name for a standard lookup. I don't know that it's documented anywhere that that's the case, but this whole shindig seems to be outside the reach of documentation.